# Is there any relationship between Simple Group and Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, ideals, simple-groups

I have studied definition of simple group. I know the fact that concept of normal subgroup is analogous to ideal in ring theory. 
A field is a ring which do not have any nontrivial ideal.
A simple group do not have any nontrivial normal subgroup. So, I have 2 questions
1) Is field and simple group are 2 equivalent concepts?
2) Does every field is a simple group under addition?

Comment: The answer is no. $\mathbb Z\triangleleft\mathbb R$ as additive groups, but $\mathbb R$ is a field. (Since fields are abelian, every subgroup is normal, so any non-trivial subgroup is also an example. Hence, only those fields with no non-trivial subgroups, i.e., prime cyclic groups, are also simple.).

Answer (score 3):

They are very different concepts. They are similar in that they are both objects with no non-trivial quotients, but they are not the same thing at all.

A field is only a simple additive group if it is exactly $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, as those are the only abelian simple groups.

Comment: I’m not sure that “objects with no non-trivial quotients” should be seen as very different concepts. Changing the category doesn’t change the concept of simplicity.

Comment: It's a question of level of understanding. The question was basically: are fields literally simple groups with an extra multiplication. So the answer is no, they are not at all, they are very different things. I don't get the feeling that "yes of course, they are the same concept of simplicity in different categories" would be interpreted correctly.